# pdflatex generates unwanted transparencies

Tags: graphics, pdftex, transparency, postscript, pdftops

`pdfLaTeX` generates PDF-page with transparency operators.

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
 \includegraphics{image.pdf}
\end{document}
```

`image.pdf` is PDF 1.4, but no transparency operators is used. If i try to generate PostScript, i get clear result without unwanted rasterization. This works fine (`pdftops` is from `poppler-utils`):

```
$ pdftops image.pdf
```

But when i try to compile `minimal.tex` and generate PostScript out of `minimal.pdf`, i get rasterized image in ps-file. The same with printing.

```
$ pdflatex minimal.tex && pdftops minimal.pdf
```

Also i tried to convert `image.pdf` to PDF 1.2 with `ghostscript`:

```
$ pdf2ps image.pdf - | ps2pdf12 - image12.pdf
```

When i include `image12.pdf` instead of `image.pdf`, i get correct result from `pdfLaTeX` (`minimal.pdf` can be correctly converted to PostsScript or to be printed).

So, can i force `pdfLaTeX` to import PDF 1.4 files with PDF 1.2 compatibility?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on our [our starter page](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: I don't think so. AFAIK, `pdflatex` does not perform any conversions to embedded PDF images. My assumption is, that your image _does_ contain a transparency operator, but `pdftops` and `gs` are clever enough to detect it as a no-op in the image file, but no longer if it got embedded inside `minimal.pdf`. I would just convert the image to PDF 1.3 and for good.

Comment: Are you _really_ sure that pdfTeX is producing incorrect PDF and not your PostScript rasterizing process?

Comment: With no example graphic and no feedback on the comments, we can't really answer here. I'm saying 'unclear' as a result.